# Pandas create new column ID based on values from other columns need to be matched

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to programming and Pandas. Therefore, please do not judge strictly and sorry for my explanations.

I have basically two-columns (DM1_ID, DM2_ID) and I need to create a new column('NewID') base on those two columns values. Basically I'm doing is creating a new ID for both columns. Here first evaluate the value in the 1st column and get that value and put it into the 'NewID' column.
Also, when we do that, need to consider DM2_ID and when that id comes in DM1_ID I need to give the same DM1_ID in NewID column.

As an example in 0 indexe has DM1_ID 1 and DM2_ID 6, I need to put 1 as NewID for both ids. When DM1_ID comes to 6 (index 15) no matter what in DM2_ID I need to give the 1 as NewID since I gave both DM1_ID 1 and DM1_ID 6. So it will be 1. Also, I need to consider that DM2_ID to latter use and it'll be also 1.
(index 15 DM1_ID 6, and DM2_ID 45 since I already gave newId as 1 for both 1 and 6 I have to give 1 for DM1_ID 6. Also for 45, I need to give 1 as a NewID(index 21).)

```
#I have a large table like this
    DM1_ID  DM2_ID
0   1       6
1   1       7
2   1       15
3   2       5
4   2       10
5   3       21
6   3       28
7   3       32
8   3       35
9   4       39
10  5       2
11  5       10
12  6       1
13  6       7
14  6       15
15  6       45
16  6       55
17  7       1
18  7       6
19  7       15
20  10      75
21  45      120
22  45      10
23  10      27
24  10      28
25  2       335

#I need to create this table

    DM1_ID  DM2_ID  abc
0   1       6        1
1   1       7        1
2   1       15       1
3   2       5        2
4   2       10       2
5   3       21       3
6   3       28       3
7   3       32       3
8   3       35       3
9   4       39       4
10  5       2        2
11  5       10       2
12  6       1        1
13  6       7        1
14  6       15       1
15  6       45       1
16  6       55       1
17  7       1        1
18  7       6        1
19  7       15       1
20  10      75       2
21  45      120      1
22  45      10       2
23  10      27       2
24  10      28       2
25  2       335      2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: Kindly show all the result you expect as you final answer. The explanation is difficult to understand

Comment: It's in there on my second table. I need to create a 'abc' column thanks

Comment: Ok. What i understand is that you are try to copy `DM1_ID` to `abc`, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I want to copy DM1_ID but I also want to DM2_ID also want to be same as the DM1_ID if there is other than any number

Comment: I mean 6 also want to be 1

Comment: So the algorithm seems to be: if neither of the values in DM1_ID or DM2_ID have been seen before, use the value in DM1_ID as the index. Otherwise, use the value previously used as the index the _first time the value in either column was seen_ as the index for the current row. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want to say. Sorry about my explanation.Do you have anything in your mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal is to persist your IDs first. You can then use this persisted map table/dictionary to assign uniqued IDs once conditions are met. I have included an example with dictionary as below but you can alternatively use a database or a JSON file for persisting your given IDs:

```
df['pairs'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[0], x[1]], axis=1)
pairs = df['pairs'].tolist()

u = {}
u_ = {}
for p in pairs:
    if u:
        if not u_:
            u_ = u.copy()
        else:
            u = u_.copy()
           
        for k in list(u.keys()):
            if any(x in u[k] for x in p):
                u_.update(
                    {
                        k: list(set(u[k] + p))
                    }
                )
                
            else:
                pass
            
        vals = [j for i in list(u.values()) for j in i]
        if u == u_ and not any(x in vals for x in p):
            n = max(list(u_.keys())) + 1
            u_[n] = p

        else:
            pass
            
    else:
        u[1] = p
        
u_
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 6, 7, 45, 15, 55, 120],
 2: [75, 2, 10, 5],
 3: [32, 35, 3, 21, 28],
 4: [4, 39]}
```

Now let's apply a function that assigns new ID per row based on the dictionary we have created in the previous step:

```
f = lambda x: next(k for k,v in u_.items() if any(i in v for i in x))
df['new_ID'] = df['pairs'].apply(f)
df.drop('pairs', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```
DM1_ID  DM2_ID  new_ID
0   1   6   1
1   1   7   1
2   1   15  1
3   2   5   2
4   2   10  2
5   3   21  3
6   3   28  3
7   3   32  3
8   3   35  3
9   4   39  4
10  5   2   2
11  5   10  2
12  6   1   1
13  6   7   1
14  6   15  1
15  6   45  1
16  6   55  1
17  7   1   1
18  7   6   1
19  7   15  1
20  10  75  2
21  45  120 1
```

Comment: 22 45 10 1
23 10 27 1
24 10 28 1
25 2 335 2

Comment: I got 45 and 10 in index 22. and have these values in index 22 to  23 and it's messing the newID column. I mean 23 and 24 indexes should need to get  NewID as 2 because in #4 index has 2 and 10.  But it getting 1. Any idea to change the code?                                                                                                    22. 45 10 1
23. 10 27 1
24. 10 28 1
25. 2 335 2

Comment: It looks like you have edited the question and introduced a new dataset as well as the expected output. It might be better to leave the original question and submit a new question to avoid any confusion for future reference. The presumption for the above solution was DM1_ID and DM2_ID pairs in each row can only belong to a unique new_ID group. If for instance each element in the row-wise pairs can theoretically belong to multiple new_ID groups as in index 22, then you may need to specify your preference criteria e.g. what is you preferred resolve algorithm for conflicts.